# libGDX Where should i use dispose / how to make an object disposeable?

Tags: java, libgdx, dispose

I would like to know:

1. I have a Stage and it holds an Actor class. Do I have to disopse the Texture and Sprite?

   ```
   public class SimpleImage extends Image {

       protected Sprite sprite;

       public SimpleImage(FileHandle file) {
           super();
           sprite = new Sprite(new Texture(file));
       }

       @Override
       public void draw(Batch batch, float parentAlpha) {
           super.draw(batch, parentAlpha);
           sprite.draw(batch);
           batch.setColor(this.getColor());
       }

       @Override
           public void act(float delta) {
           super.act(delta);
       }

       @Override
       protected void positionChanged() {
           super.positionChanged();
           sprite.setPosition(getX(), getY());
       }
   }
   ```
2. How to make obj disposable? In the Java libs are two: MediaDisposer.Disposable and MediaDisposer.ResourceDisposer.
3. When do I need to make a obj disposable?

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to apply [separation of concerns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns). Your `SimpleImage` class should not have to care about managing assets. As such, you should not create the `Texture` in your `SimpleImage` class in the first place. And thus you shouldn't have to dispose it.

Managing assets it usually done by using an [AssetManager](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Managing-your-assets).

Also, you should [pack your images](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Texture-packer) into a single `Texture`. Meaning that you can't just use one `Texture` per `SimpleImage`, but instead would use one `Texture` for multiple `SimpleImage`s (or other classes that need an image).

So you should reconsider your approach. That said, let me answer your questions.

1. You need to dispose everything that implements the [Disposable](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/utils/Disposable.html) interface. [Texture](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/Texture.html) implements the `Disposable` interface, [Sprite](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g2d/Sprite.html) doesn't.
2. If you want to make your object implement the `Disposable` interface then make it implement the `Disposable` interface. It's `com.badlogic.gdx.utils.Disposable` if you're having trouble importing it. [It's a libGDX interface](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/gdx/src/com/badlogic/gdx/utils/Disposable.java) and has nothing to do with MediaDisposer.
3. You could make an object disposable when it is responsible for disposing resources. Typically this means that is responsible for calling the `.dispose()` method on member objects it created. You don't have to make them disposable though, as long as you make sure that you dispose the resources you are creating, then it's fine.

Comment: How should I solte the Actors or how you solte your Actors? Add methods to them to do different actions like scaling, coloring, etc.

Comment: What's a solte and how is that related to the question?

Comment: How should i build my Actors? Add methods for actions or make for each image that schould be displayed on the screen an Actor. Example: I have a logo image and want a fade in / out animation. For an Game background should I use the same Actor but here I want no fade in / out?

Comment: That's quite a broad question which isn't related to your original question. Consider asking a new question instead and include more details, what you've tried and why that didn't work for you. http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking